# powershell Generate a list with all others folders name

Tags: list, powershell

let's say i have an array with folders name like this `$list=@("folder1","folder2","folder3")` and I want to generate a second list with all the others folders in that path but exclude my list. How can I do that?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Path SomePath -Exclude $list -Directory -Name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-exclude` switch of `Get-ChildItem`.

```
$array = @("Thing1", "Thing2", "Thing3")
GCI -Path "Directory Name" -Exclude $array
```

And if you only want folders to show you can add the `-Directory` switch

```
GCI -Path "Directory Name" -Exclude $array -Directory
```